# running default alloy appcelerator application

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am new to appcelerator and i'm trying to run the default alloy project (mvc).when the project in executed on the browser,this is what it displays
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=136441tita.jpg
(it's supposed to show an onclick button that shows a message : hello world)

when i execute the classic default project it works perfectly.so am i missing something or file that need to be configured ?

i also tried different versions of sdk,run it on android emulator,but there is always the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing, new mobile project, default alloy project, then selected Mobile Web Preview in Browser and Run. Shows up as expected. Not sure why you wouldn't get the same. Must be something in your configuration because as default configured it worked for me.